# In Ephesians 2:15 exactly what part of the Law has been abolished?

Tags: law, ephesians, pauline-epistles, sacrifice, ten-commandments

St Paul, speaking in the context of Jew and Gentile being brought together, declares that the "law of commandments" were abolished.

> "For he himself is our peace, who has made us both one and has broken
>   down in his flesh the dividing wall of hostility **by abolishing the
>   law of commandments expressed in ordinances**, that he might create in
>   himself one new man in place of the two." (Ephesians 2:15)

Exactly what law (or part of law) is that which is 'expressed in ordinances', and abolished?  Is he referring to the Mosaic system in its entirety, or does it only refer to the ceremonial aspects pertaining to feasts and temple sacrifices?

Comment: All the answers are based on the translation given in this question, a translation that might be wrong.  Some versions *do* translate it that way, but the more literal versions, those that try to stick to the original Greek rather than paraphrasing what they think is the meaning.  NKJV for example translates verses 15 and 16 as "*by abolishing in his flesh the enmity … thereby putting to death the enmity*. Notice that it is "*the enmity*" that was abolished and put to death, not the commandments. Less literal translations lose this truth. With a literal translation, this question becomes moot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The law given to Moses at Sinai was abrogated with the advent of the new covenant. To put it a better way: The entirety of the Mosaic Covenant was fulfilled in Christ. The law of Moses no longer serves as direct and immediate judge over the lives and conduct of God's people. God's children today obey the Law of Christ [Gal 6.2, 1 Cor 9:21].

Jesus, who is better than Moses, in his sermon on the mount served as the new law giver establishing his new commandments **[Matt 5:19**]. In that sermon he expounded on the law that **Jer 31** said would be written in the believer's inward parts. The law written on man's heart is vastly different than the ministration of death written on tablets of stone [2 Cor 4:7]. The former comes as a result of God's  gracious gift of faith which results in the new birth. The latter was a non-gracious covenant with terms that were "obey or perish" [Gal 3:12].

**Significant passages related to distinction and supremacy of new covenant over old.**

*For the priesthood being changed, there is made of necessity a **change also of the law**. Hebrews 7:12*

The writer of Hebrews had the word "better" in mind when he wrote his epistle. Christ is better than angels, Joshua, Moses, and Aaron. The change in the law came as a result of a better law giver. One whose laws would be obeyed because of a changed heart. The old covenant had absolutely no power over the flesh.

*Rom 8:3  For **what the law couldn’t do**, in that it was weak through the flesh, God did, sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh and for sin, he condemned sin in the flesh;*

*For if that first covenant had been faultless, then should no place have been **sought for the second**. Hebrews 8:7*

Again, the supremacy of the second, or new covenant. The fault laid in man's inability to obey God, not in God's law which was a reflection of His character.

*In that he saith, A new covenant, he hath made the first old. Now that which decayeth and waxeth old is ready to vanish away. Hebrews 8:13 (KJV)*

The writer of Hebrews warns those who considered abandoning Christ and going back to following the law by pointing out that it was about to disappear.

Lastly, I need to be clear on the entirety of the law's fulfillment in Christ. I mention that because some traditions divide the Mosaic law into three general categories: civil, moral, and ceremonial laws, as if some laws may still apply while others were abrogated. In God's word you'll find no such divisions.

*Hos 6:6  For it is love that I seek, and not sacrifice; knowledge of God more than burnt offerings.*

Comment: So what is "the Law of Christ"? Is it "[You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your might](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=deut+6%3A5&version=ESV)", is it "[you shall love your neighbor as yourself](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=lev+19%3A18&version=ESV)"?

Comment: Jack: Both of those are correct. It is the same to what Jesus commanded in John 13:34:35 [34] A new commandment I give to you, that you love one another. Just as I have loved you, you also love one another. 
Joh 13:35  By this everyone will know that you are my disciples, if you have love for one another

Comment: OT ref to new covenant "new heart": Deu 30:6  And the LORD your God will circumcise your heart and the heart of your offspring, so that you will love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul, that you may live.

Comment: This is an excellent answer Wiberteric and hard to improve upon.



 
wilberteric

Comment: Is there a passage from Christ -not from Paul or others- saying that He did away with the law?

Comment: Please see my answer to the question [How is the Law changed in Hebrews 7:12?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/20458)

Comment: @wilberteric  (-1) If the law was abrogated then how does circumcision put one back under the curse of the law?

Comment: @woundedEgo...please give Biblical ref and I will respond.

Comment: @wilberteric  If the law as abrogated ("repealed") then what is the problem with being circumcised?  NIV Gal 5:3 "Again I declare to every man who lets himself be circumcised that he is obligated to obey the whole law." Neither Jesus nor Paul repealed the law at all. Jesus restored the integrity of the law. "Fulfilling" the law (by obeying it) does not "use it up" like a one-use pregnancy kit or a prophecy. The law, every jot and tittle is in tact. And the new covenant is only with the houses of Israel and Judah. The law just has no jurisdiction in the new regime.

Comment: Good answer but with minor errors. The Law of Christ is also based on works- obey or perish; bear fruits or cut off to hell. The gracious part of the new covenant is only with respect to the liberty from the Mosaic law. That's what grace is.

Comment: "The gracious part of the new covenant is only with respect to the liberty from the Mosaic law. That's what grace is". I'm afraid I have to disagree. The gracious part of the new NC is that it requires no works on our part.  Obeying/bearing fruit is the direct consequence of being a recipient of grace,  they're not works.

Comment: @ruminator  if the new convenant is only with the house of Israel and Judah.  How does it apply to us Gentiles.

Comment: I have come to understand that "The Israel of God" is Israel resurrected, without regard for genetics or Torah observance. There is neither Jew nor Gentile in the New Creation.

Answer (score 8):

Although Paul does not use the same word for 'abolish' as Jesus in Matthew 5:17, I think it helpful to bear that verse in mind, as Paul did not intend to contradict what Jesus says:

> <sup>17</sup>“Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. <sup>18</sup>For truly, I say to you, until heaven and earth pass away, not an iota, not a dot, will pass from the Law until all is accomplished. <sub><sub>[ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/mat5.17-18)</sub></sub>

So apart from asking 'which part' of the law is abolished, it is also necessary to decide exactly what sense that 'abolition' is meant in both contexts.

1. 'not abolish' in Matthew 5 and 'abolish' in Ephesians have ***the same outcome***; namely, to bring about heart-obedience and a genuine love for God:

   - In Matthew 5, Jesus directs our attention to the intention of the law; that it [concerns the heart and can be obeyed only from the heart](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/7742/43).
   - In Ephesians, Paul speaks of the abolition of the law leading to the creation of one 'new man', in whom obedience is rooted in trying to '[discern what is pleasing to the Lord](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=eph+5%3A7-11&version=ESV)' with '[a sincere heart](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=eph+6%3A5-8&version=ESV)', which is the antithesis of following the letter of the law for appearances' sake.<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>
2. 'not abolish' in Matthew 5 and 'abolish' in Ephesians have ***the same enemy***; that is, those who treat the law as commands to 'obey' (i.e. *appear* to obey), rather than an opportunity to please God:

   - In Matthew 5, the enemy of the law is *a form of obedience to the law* that is not righteousness. In each case where Jesus says 'You have heard that it was said...' he has the outward, superficial, letter-of-the-law interpretation in mind, and has in his sights those who '...[prophesy in your name, and cast out demons in your name, and do many mighty works in your name](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew+7%3A22&version=ESV)...' whom He calls '...[workers of lawlessness](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew+7%3A23&version=ESV)', not those who disregard the law entirely.
   - In Ephesians, those who appeal to the letter of the law in order to deny Gentiles access to God through Christ are God's enemies: now *both* Jew *and* Gentile are '...[being built together into a dwelling place for God by the *Spirit*](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians+2%3A19-22&version=ESV)' - in other words, at the level of the heart and intentions<sup><sup>2</sup></sup> and not outward form. The new heart (or spirit) promised by the prophets<sup><sup>3</sup></sup> is realized in the work of Christ in building this church.

With these things in mind, I suggest Paul's strong language, when speaking of the abolition of '...the law of commandments expressed in ordinances...', refers to exposing and sweeping away of the legalistic interpretation of the law, which Jesus also condemned. Paul encourages this interpretation with the words '...commandments expressed in ordinances...' This is the understanding of the law as '...[precept upon precept, line upon line](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isa+28%3A9-13&version=ESV)...' that has always been wrong, and has always been the source of hostility between Jew and Gentile<sup><sup>4</sup></sup>.

> *Exactly what law (or part of law) is that which is 'expressed in ordinances', and abolished? Is he referring to the Mosaic system in its entirety, or does it only refer to the ceremonial aspects pertaining to feasts and temple sacrifices?*

#### Paul is referring to the legalistic interpretation of the Mosaic law in its entirety. He is not referring specifically to 'ceremonial aspects'. These are the parts of the law which may be the easiest to pay lip-service to, but the same is done to the rest, with hearts far from God.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *cf [Romans 2:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+2%3A25-29&version=ESV), [2 Corinthians 3:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%203&version=ESV)*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *see also [3:16-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians+3%3A14-19&version=ESV)*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *see [Psalm 51](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+51%3A10-12&version=ESV), [Joel 2:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=joel+2%3A28-32&version=ESV), [Jeremiah 31:33](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=jer+31%3A31-34&version=ESV), Ezekiel [11:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ez+11%3A14-21&version=ESV) & [36:26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel+36%3A22-32&version=ESV)*</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *for example, this attitude is evident in [Mark 2:23-28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark+2%3A23-28&version=ESV)*</sub>

Comment: Good answer, but what to do until children are grown up to understand it ? I think deut 6 still applies

Comment: Fine job, Jack! I took the liberty of tidying things up a bit, but your observations are spot on, in my opinion. Don

Comment: (-1) How does a proper interpretation of the law get deemed an abolishment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39792/discussion-between-jack-douglas-and-woundedego).

Comment: Paul said that if you get circumcised you become beholden to the law again and fall from divine favor and come under a curse. It speaks of no longer being under a tutor. Paul talks of being "dead to the law" and "free from the law". This answer has good notions but on a different subject. This doesn't address "abolishment" at all.

Comment: Would be correct to say Paul views "abolishing the law of commandments expressed in ordinances" as "abolishing legalism(nomism)" (i.e, abolishing legalism as in legalism within the field of thelogy) ?

Comment: @crazyTech yes I think so, or to put it another way, abolishing the primacy of external obedience over obedience that originates from the heart and thus has a different nature (even if sometimes apparently similar expression). This is neatly expressed in the imagery of the commandments engraved on tablets of stone versus "I will put my law within them, and I will write it on their hearts"

Comment: Very good and though provoking answer indeed.  +1.

Answer (score 3):

> Exactly what part of the Law has been abolished?

All the animal sacrifices, the literal understanding or Dead Letter and all ritualistic applications of the Mosaic Law have all been abolished.

Jesus-Christ, the sinless Great High Priest in the order of Melchizedek, the red heifer, has replaced all animal sacrifices with the shedding of his blood.

> Hebrew 10:4 Berean Literal Bible
>
> For it is impossible for the blood of bulls and of goats to take away
>   sins.

The moral, spiritual, and prophetic aspects of the Mosaic Law still stand and were never abolished by Jesus and the apostles. Jesus took the Mosaic Law from the literal understanding to a higher dimension, which is the spiritual or kingdom realm. We now offer spiritual sacrifices through the blood of Jesus.

> Matthew 5:17 Berean Study Bible
>
> Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I
>   have not come to abolish them, but to fulfil them.
>
> 1 Peter 2:4-7 (NKJV) - The Chosen Stone and His Chosen People
>
> Coming to Him as to a living stone, rejected indeed by men, but chosen
>   by God and precious, **you also, as living stones, are being built up
>   a spiritual house, a holy priesthood, to offer up spiritual sacrifices
>   acceptable to God through Jesus Christ.**
>
> Romans 12:1-2 (NKJV) - Living Sacrifices to God
>
> I beseech you, therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, **that you
>   present your bodies a living sacrifice,** holy, acceptable to God,
>   which is your reasonable service. And do not be conformed to this
>   world, but be transformed by the renewing of your mind, that you may
>   prove what is that good and acceptable and perfect will of God.

Faith and praise are considered to be spiritual sacrifices

> Hebrew 13:15 Berean Study Bible
>
> Through Jesus, therefore, **let us continually offer to God a
>   sacrifice of praise,** the fruit of lips that confess His name.
>
> Hebrews 11:4 Berean Literal Bible
>
> **By faith Abel offered to God a more excellent sacrifice than Cain,** through which he was testified to be righteous, God bearing witness to
>   his gifts; and through it, having died, he still speaks.

Answer (score 1):

Given the context, the word translated "abolished" should be translated "deactivated" or "obviated". Paul's point is that in the new regime the law is not relevant and righteousness is on the basis of faith. What changed is not the law but the believing Jew who "died to the law" and thus is no longer beholden to it:

> BSB Romans 7: 3So then, if she is joined to another man while her
>   husband is still alive, she is called an adulteress; but if her
>   husband dies, she is free from that law and is not an adulteress, even
>   if she marries another man. 4Therefore, my brothers, you also died to
>   the Law through the body of Christ, that you might belong to another,
>   to Him who was raised from the dead, in order that we might bear fruit
>   to God.

The gentiles however were never "under" (beholden to) the law so they didn't need to die to the law.

So now the law is not a barrier in the new regime.

Answer (score 1):

The law of sin and death the law of Moses we do not follow any more. We now follow after a new law, "The law of the spirit of life in Christ Jesus." Which will make a man free from sin and death. Jesus came with life so we can sin no more. We walk in the spirit now under Christ's law of spirit and life. We are now washed in the blood of Jesus by his words. In the old law which was a shadow of things to come they where just covered. Blood doesn't cover nothing today after the Son of God Jesus Christ was slain on the cross, it washes. Silly perverted and bewitched proud knowing nothing preachers for not consenting to the wholesome words of Jesus Christ the Son of God our Lord, are all covered  and dammed to hell fire and brimstone for not receiving the love of the truth which is Christ in you the hope of glory. We now have it inside us the word, in Moses' day it was on stone an outward appearance. Today it starts from the inside out. In Moses' day they observed days, times, months, and years. Today Christ fulfilled everything, now he did his end we have to do ours.

See Romans 8:1-4; John 1:17-18; Luke 22:36-37; Luke 24:44; Hebrews 9:1-28; 10:1-22; 7:11-24; II Corinthians 3:1-18.

Answer (score 1):

The law was abolished through the fulfillment of it by the death of Christ. The righteousness of fulfilling it is by grace imputed to the elect. Therefore to him unto whom it is thus imputed, that man is not under the law, but under grace. By His death Judaism was abolished. There is no such thing as Judaism today, as evidenced by the fact that there is no religion today in which a high priest, an altar, and a sacrifice typifying a yet to come Messiah exists, nor ever again shall be. For the shadow and type passed away upon the manifestation of the substance and reality that the Lamb slain before the foundation of the world, who by himself hath made certain complete and permanent propitiation for all of the saints (the Israel of God) both old testament and new ,at Calvary hath now prevailed.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  Are you able to provide any Bible or other references to support your assertions?

Comment: I am intrigued by your first sentence, "The law was abolished through the fulfillment of it by the death of Christ." when Matt 5:17-19 specifically says that Jesus did not come to abolish the law?

Answer (score 1):

It is the law in its old authority, Moses wrote it with his hand (Deu 31) and it was a witness against his people. This handwriting was "nailed to the cross" and i know some disagree, but it is obvious. A jew shall not become a gentile and a gentile not a jew. Both becomes a new man in Christ. The law separated them. And it condemned (curse) if breaking it. Now both are free to observe it without condemnation...or not. But they ought to abide in Christ by keeping his commands and words spoken in the gospel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Bible Mystery: the truth about law by connecting these dots

- Matthew 6:13 KJV: Our Father ... deliver us from **evil**.
- Romans 7:6 KJV: now we are delivered from the **law**.
- Romans 14:23 KJV: whatsoever is **not of faith** is sin.
- Galatians 3:12 KJV: And the law is **not of faith**
- Matthew 12:29 KJV: first bind the **strong** man (of sin)
- 1 Corinthians 15:56 KJV: the **strength** of sin is the law
- Romans 4:15 KJV where no law, there no **transgression**
- 1Timothy 2:14 being deceived, was in the **transgression**

Law is about good and evil; But law itself is "both good and evil".
Law is lastly the "evil concupiscence" which produces "evil fruit".

Example: Romans 7
Paul tried "another law": aka law2:
"the second" law of Mt 22:36-40: "Love thy neighbour".
He had assumed such to be a commandment unto life;
But found it was a commandment unto death: Rom 7:10.
By law2, when he'd do good, "evil was present": Rom 7:21.
Law2 he supposed good, brought him in "captivity" to law1.
Then law1 wrought "all manner of concupiscence" in him.
It made him do things he would not do, when free of law;
Then hounded with a guilt trip until "wretched" as PTSD.

So when Paul says beware of "evil workers": Philippians 3:2;
he is allegorically referring to law workers, which he named in Galatians 2:9, namely James, Cephas (Peter), and John.

That's why Apostle Paul clarifies this in 2 Corinthians 3:
all law, written in stone and ink, should be "done away".

Because the law worketh **wrath**: Romans 4:15; And God
hath not appointed us to **wrath**: 1 Thessalonians 5:9. For
in Ephesians 4:31 law = **wrath** is what to "put away".

The grace of our Lord Jesus Christ [be] with you all. Amen.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to read "abolish" as having a very particular meaning in Paul's writings when it comes to the law.

For Paul, because his ministry so heavily focused on the Gentiles (those not born as Jews), the dominant theological question of his writing is "what does it mean for Gentiles to be saved?"

There were a lot of very prominent voices in the early church who demanded that Gentiles first submit to all the Jewish laws, in other words convert to Judaism, before they could be welcomed into the church. This meant things like males being circumcised (something Greeks and Romans almost never did) and Gentile converts keeping Kosher diets. The logic of their position was that God had a particular relationship with Israel, so to be saved Gentiles had to join the Jewish community first and enter into that relationship.

Paul takes a different view: he believes that God has always meant to use Israel to establish a new covenant with all of humanity. Jesus establishes that covenant, and since it is for everyone, Gentile believers don't have to convert to Judaism first. So for example, Paul compares Jesus to a new "Adam" in Romans 5, arguing that the relationship with God that Jesus establishes is for all people, not a particular nation. And he argues very explicitly in Galatians against forcing Gentile converts to follow Jewish dietary laws or to be circumcised.

In the text that you cited, I think what Paul means is that Jesus has removed the barrier to entry for Gentiles seeking a relationship with God. Because of the new covenant, they don't have to adhere to the law in order to enter that relationship: the law as the "gate-keeper" of who is in the covenant and who is out has been "abolished."

So it's a very specific meaning of "abolish" that Paul has in mind, I think.

Comment: +1 ignore the DV - this is a well argued answer and useful.

Comment: (-1) The new covenant was only with "the house of Israel and Judah" so does not solve the problem.

Comment: The new covenant was not made with gentiles to free them from being required to fulfill the law because the gentiles never were under the law! It was made with the Jews because they had transgressed the law.

Answer (score 0):

The law was given because of all the trespasses 430 years after the promise to Abraham. The law was a school master and a guardian only until Messiah. Messiah fulfilled the law and was the seed of promise to Abraham. Those under law are the children of Abraham through Ishmael those who live by faith are the children of Abraham through Isaac the promised child. Yeshua is the promised seed, singular not plural. The righteous shall live by faith. Yeshua gave us new ToraH IN TWO COMMANDMENTS lOVE GOD AND LOVE YOUR NEIGHBOR. There s no need for any other Torah, no reason to be circumcised, no reason to keep   the law of commandments contained in ordinances; no flesh will be justified through keeping of the OLD Torah. We have a better law giver and a better covenant in Yeshua. Gal 3:10  For all who rely on the deeds of Torah are under a curse—for the Scriptures say, “Cursed is everyone who does not keep doing everything written in the scroll of the Torah.Gal 3:26  For you are all sons of God through trusting in Messiah Yeshua.Gal 5:18  But if you are led by the Ruach, you are not under law.Gal 3:29  And if you belong to Messiah, then you are Abraham’s seed—heirs according to the promise. The old torah disappeared Gal 3:25  But now that faith has come, we are no longer under a guardian.Blessed be God the Father of our Lord and Yeshua our Messiah.

Comment: Welcome!  First, all answers need to address focussing on the question. Second, the text in question, Eph. 2:15 refers, in view of v 14, to "sacrificial laws, but  NOT "TORAH" altogether. Third, the law of "love" by Jesus does NOT negate the "TORAH", rather, He was saying: all the laws and prophets hang on these TWO commandments.  I would recommend "Biblehub.com" for  a Biblical research for a start.

Comment: @Sam The new user has expressed (adequately) an answer. If you differ, you are free to offer your own answer. What the user expresses is quite correct in that the Law as such is abolished in Christ, as states Paul. (Again, if you differ, kindly state your own answer.)

Comment: Welcome to BH. May I suggest that you do not use capitals for emphasis. Many feel it is akin to 'shouting' in text. Better to use italics for emphasis, I find. And please consider paragraphs as an aid to your reader. One point of your argument, then a paragraph break avoids presenting a 'wall of text' to your reader. Please take the Tour and see the Help (below).

Answer (score 0):

According to Mike, "ordinances" is not referring to written Torah. He is referring to "the traditions of man" found in the Oral Traditions. The Oral Traditions which are recorded in the Mishnah (and commented on in the Talmud) are Pharisaic laws. In other words, there are Two Torahs to distinguish from in the Gospels and the Letters. The common mistake many make when trying to determine what this verse means is not distinguishing what Torah is being dealt with (Written vs Oral Tradition). This obviously makes all the difference when a final understanding of the content is rendered."
Can we conclude that the abolished law is the law of the Jews. That is, the Jewish man made law.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: @Emmanuel Interesting answer. This drawing of differentiating line between two Thoras is important. However, I guess, according to Paul the Law as such, the very written Law, contained in itself its own abolition at arrival of Messiah; just like a silk-worm contains in itself its own abolition at "coming" of wings to it and then it is no more a silk-worm but a butterfly. Thus, analogously, Christ is a wing-provider to us, worms, so that we may be butterflies and be able to fly to His Kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

If one has a child, and the toddler awakens in him than Paul's teaching that "THE LAW INCRESETH SIN" one can see first hand, the rotten fruit of the first fruit! For the newer parents, Whatever he/she is whining about,  let it hit a crescendo. Then give that human brat the truck or whatever. Then watch their faces as you put them ALONE in whatever room, and tell him- "You love this so much, do not stop playing until I say so," Oh my, you see the fallen man desires to be seen, and the lure of what he is missing..the smell of dinner, the laughter, If you do this ONCE , he will balance the cost of any other
, future tantrum.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

(Because there are four parties included in this verse, there are four viewpoints or aspects that I feel I should address here) :

Firstly Christ has dealt with the sin question and became sin for us. He has taken upon himself that which has marred the image of God, as defined by God's perfect character in the ten commandments. The Son of God has taken on the guilt, shame, grief, separation from the Father, and all the suffering of man upon himself. He has taken all this and most importantly he has taken all the temptations that we would bear, upon his own fully human frame. He has endured all this in weak, mortal flesh, and experienced those temptations as we would experience them. While here in this world, he has given all of himself to us during his life and has taken all that we are, upon himself in his death. He has done all this and has overcome.

Christ has fulfilled his role as the lamb of God and brought to an end the requirements, of the sanctuary service that pointed to him. He has made redundant those rituals, which became a stumbling stone for his people.

Secondly, the law encapsulated in ceremonies, instead of reminding the sinner of his sin, had become a mask by which the sinner thought he could cover his un-penitent heart. The covenant of faith with Abraham had been forgotten and the law of ordinances which was intended to remind them, became an outward form, a mindless ritual for the unconvicted soul. The death of the innocent animal had lost all meaning, and so in the mind of the sinner, instead of the sacrifice being an act of divine mercy granted by Yahweh to the failing one, to remind them of the Savior to come: Instead of the ritual being an act of faith, whereby symbolically the merits of the innocent were transferred to the sinner, the ritual began to resemble a bloodthirsty pagan sacrifice, whereby the unpenitent hand holding the bloody instrument wielded itself as though it were the means of salvation.

Had God's people approached their maker with eyes of faith, they would have been further awakened by the ordinances, being instructed by the ceremonies and devotions of the priest; if they emulated the spiritual precepts that fashioned these outward practices, in their own lives, they would have heeded the call to love, justice, and mercy. But instead, their hearts became benumbed and indifferent towards their redeemer. And yet God's people were required to be his representative to the rest of the world.

Thirdly, for the Gentiles, the main focus was the things of this life, and so the eternal aspects of the Jewish rituals would have been meaningless to them. But for the gentile, the idea of forgiveness implies that there is someone to fear, and the pagans of the Roman era tended to disregard the idea that the gods were to be feared, and those that did look upon them with fear were regarded as 'superstitio ' or superstitious. The relationship with the gods, therefore, was considered to be mutually beneficial, and through philosophy, as well, the goal was wisdom in self-direction and self-reliance.

The Gentile had no other one he could look to, apart from himself, who truly represented his innermost need. All were trapped in sin, Jew and Gentile alike. For Gentiles, the Jews had in effect become the hypocrites, the false shepherds. For some of the Jews, the only apparent evidence of their purity was not that they embodied the faith of Abraham, but rather that they kept themselves separate from the 'unclean' Gentiles, and so did not associate with or even try to convert them.

The idea of perfection and faithfulness to a single God only was foolishness to the Gentile mind, which attempted to downplay the severity of the fallen human condition. However, their consciences were still convicted for their failings, their thoughts accusing or else excusing one another. (Rom 2:15)

The mindset of the Jew was to focus on religious rules that gave structure and a sense of security to everyday life. However, the law of ordinances became a stumbling block for those that depended on it; and a wall that separated, for those outside the ceremonial sanctuary system. And yet the Gentiles, many of them had their own rituals, their own animal sacrifices, their own ceremonies involving the shedding of blood. But to even think that a person could satisfy the gods without a bribe (which was always by the works of his own hands); Or, that is, to even contemplate the idea of bridging the heavenly chasm to a righteous God, who does not accept bribes (Deut 10:17), would have been beyond imagination to the Gentile.

The New Man:
But Christ has broken down the dividing wall that separated, by fulfilling the Law, in his own body, both the moral and the ceremonial law, being the perfect and unblemished lamb of God. He has brought an end, through the sacrifice of himself, the ceremonial law, while confirming the validity and precepts of the moral Law by his ability to keep God's Ten Commandments, effectively restoring the image of God to the frame of man.

Christ has in himself declared it possible to be free from sin. He has become the ideal also for the Gentile, that seeks such freedom and the guiding influence of a life lived in faith and perfection.

For the Jew, the law was meant to be a pattern upon which to build faith, but the law ended up being a substitute for faith instead. As the apostle Paul had said, “Is the law then against the promises of God? God forbid: for if there had been a law given which could have given life, verily righteousness should have been by the law.” — Galatians 3:21 (KJV).
For the Gentile who was inwardly seeking an ideal to rest his faith upon, he had no firm foundation while he rejected the forms and apparent restrictions of the law.

But in Christ we have the very Law of God embodied in the life of Christ, our ideal, who has done so, not by any appointment to Levitical services, but by his walk of perfect faith in the eternal Father.

> Who is made, not after the law of a carnal commandment, but after the power of an endless life. — Hebrews 7:16 (KJV)

(Conclusion):
We have one who has broken down the hostility, that is, the law of directions in fleshly forms and ceremonies, creating one new man, that has met the requirements of the Law by faith, so making peace. (See Eph 2:15)

We now have One whom we can emulate, as we walk in his footsteps, following the Lamb wherever he goes, being guided and joined together by the Holy Spirit, we now have new life in Christ, both Jew and Gentile. (See also vs 16-22).

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score -2):

"Law of commandments expressed in ordinances" is not referring to written Torah. He is referring to "the traditions of man" found in the Oral Traditions. The Oral Traditions which are recorded in the Mishnah (and commented on in the Talmud) are Pharisaic laws. In other words, there are Two Torahs to distinguish from in the Gospels and the Letters. The common mistake many make when trying to determine what this verse means is not distinguishing what Torah is being dealt with (Written vs Oral Tradition). This obviously makes all the difference when a final understanding of the content is rendered.

Jesus set the Jews (and Gentiles alike of course) free from man-made religious law. Written Torah is NOT man made!

See also:

Roth, Andrew Gabriel. "Ephesians Chapter 2." Aramaic English New Testament: Mari : A Compilation, Annotation and Translation of the Eastern Original Aramaic New Testament Peshitta Text. 5th Ed., Peshitta English Aramaic Critical ed. Bellingham, Wash.: Netzari, 2009. 580. Print. footnote #22 Roth's translation from Aramaic distinguishes Written Torah from Oral Tradition through out the Gospels and Letters.

Comment: (-1) Paul is never concerned with oral law.

Comment: @WoundedEgo Here is a pericope from the 1901 Jewish Encyclopedia: The earliest name for the oral teachings was "miẓwat zeḳenim" (Suk. 46a). In the New Testament it is called παραδόσεις τῶν πρεσβυτέρων, and by Josephus and Philo παράδοσις ἄγραφος τῶν πατέρων διαδοχή.   ------ So as you can see Paul did indeed talk about the Oral Torah and at the end of the day his refusal to follow it is why the Pharisees and other sects went after him and falsely accused him of not following Jewish law. It wasn't written torah he was ignoring, it most certainly was the Oral Torah.

Comment: So when did Paul speak of παράδοσις ἄγραφος τῶν πατέρων διαδοχή?

Comment: aka wounded ego.